# how to decrease deploying size of GAE app?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gae-eclipse-plugin

I want to deploy about 600mb of static files into Google app engine but I can't. It throws an exception that the deploysize is over 1GB. I just use GAE as an static file provider, my GAE app doesn't have any code. The static file are PNG and JPEG files.
Is there any way to decrease deploying size?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Google Cloud Storage is better suited to this use, you can configure a bucket to serve a static web site, see https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration

Answer (score 1):

Why use Google App Engine for that?

There are tons of free hosting offers out there. Deploying files with an FTP client is also faster, more flexible than the app engine deployment.

Comment: I use GAE just because it is free. If you know other free hosting which as good as gae, please advice me

Answer (score 0):

> the total size of all files for all versions exceeds the initial free 1 gigabyte, then there will be a $ 0.026 per GB per month charge.

You have two options:

- Enable billing for your application
- Store your files in Blobstore, and deploy only files you need for your app logic

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy less than 1GB of files and get this error message, chances are that you are logged in using the wrong account. Make sure you deploy your app with the correct credentials.

Comment: I see this error every time when I try to deploy from Eclipse and forget to switch accounts in Google Eclipse Plugin.